# Extracting a number from a string using regex and vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Given a string with a numeric value in it, I need to extract that value and assign it to a variable. I use the following to accomplish that:

```
Dim m as Match = Regex.Match(str, "\d+")
If m.Success Then
    test = m.Groups(0).Value
End If
```

It works fine for string like this one:

```
This is a 4308 number
```

I get `4308` extracted. However, if the numeric value contains commas or dots:

```
This is a 4,308 number
```

Then, the value extracted is `4` instead of `4,308` or `4308`.

How can I modify my regular expression to retrieve the whole number whether or not it contains commas and/or dots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the comma and perhaps a dot to the character class:

```
Dim m as Match = Regex.Match(str, "[\d.,]+")
```

This one is too crude since it allows strings like `.,567,..`.

You should use

```
Dim m as Match = Regex.Match(str, "\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*")
```

It will match numbers like `1`, `1,235`, `2,456.56`, `1,254,456.45`, etc.

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B.%2C%5D%5Cd%2B)*&i=1%0D%0A1%2C235%0D%0A2%2C456.56%0D%0A1%2C254%2C456.45)